# I need help making a tkinter program that variably opens a picture

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a program that has a button that will open a picture if a variable is in a certain state, and change how the button looks (or maybe show a different picture) if it's not.  I have been trying to work through the bugs I've been getting.

This is honestly intermediary code so I can understand how to make what I'm actually trying to do, make a network-enabled GUI for some physical buttons.
I've tried passing blueButton in as a variable, but that didn't work.

```
import tkinter as tk

weather = "sunny"

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.blueButton = tk.Button(self, fg = "blue")
        self.blueButton["text"] = "I'm Blue"
        self.blueButton["command"] = self.change
        self.blueButton.pack(anchor="nw")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text = "QUIT", fg = "red",
                          command = self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

        self.pack(fill = "both", expand = 1)

    def change(self):
        global weather
        if weather == "sunny":
            w = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=750)
            img = tk.PhotoImage(file = "haunter.gif")
            w.create_image((200, 200), image = img) 

            w.pack()

        else:
            self.blueButton["bitmap"] = "error"  

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Application(master = root)
app.mainloop()
```

The canvas gets made, but the picture doesn't show up, the "quit" button just moves.

I've also gotten the error "name blueButton is not defined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep the image as an attribute of your `App`, put it on a `canvas`, then show or hide the canvas depending on the weather.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk



class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.blueButton = tk.Button(self, fg = "blue")
        self.blueButton["text"] = "I'm Blue"
        self.blueButton["command"] = self.change
        self.blueButton.pack()

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text = "QUIT", fg = "red",
                          command = self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack()

        self.pack(fill = "both", expand = 1)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=750)
#         self.sunny_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="haunter.gif")
        self.sunny_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="rapporteur.gif")
        self.canvas.create_image((200, 200), image=self.sunny_img) 


    def change(self):
        weather = ['sunny', 'rainy']
        current_weather = random.choice(weather)
        if current_weather == 'sunny':
            self.canvas.pack()
            self.blueButton["bitmap"] = ''

        else:
            self.canvas.pack_forget()
            self.blueButton["bitmap"] = "error"  


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Application(master = root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well damn, that's quite smart. It fixed both my problems too, though I don't understand why it helped blueButton one. Anyway, thanks.